# Why did Lucy of future not know of the solution she wrote?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the latest episode of Fairy Tail, present Lucy discovered how to stop the prophecy from happening by reading the diary of future Lucy which suggested that by destroying the gate of Eclipse, future Rogue wont be able to come to present time hence stopping everything from happening. While a few episodes back when Natsu and group met future Lucy she told them about the future and said that she apologize because she did not have any solution.

Future Lucy wrote in her diary how to stop everything from happening by destroying the gate of eclipse. If so why did't she knew about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

There's 3 (two for now) different future, first future is when the 10000 dragons come out from the gate. This future Lucy didn't know about Rogue so she didn't know that they have to destroy the gate so Rogue won't come to the past and prevent all of this to happen. So the diary didn't consist of how to stop the prophecy, but rather she just write what she know that if the gate destroyed, it will make a chain reaction effect. Present Lucy is the one who come up with the conclusion.

[image]

Comment: oh... that first page... i never read it, is it in the manga? or somewhere else because i never saw it. thanks and i accepted the answer

Comment: yes, it's from chapter 333.