# Why didn't the Dragon slayers disappear when the eclipse gate was destroyed?

Tags: fairy-tail

During the Grand magic games, they were not able to actually defeat all the dragons that came out of Eclipse gate. The dragons as well as future Rouge and Lucy just disappeared and went back to their own timeline when the Eclipse gate was destroyed.

But as Zeref stated, Natsu and the other dragon slayers are from the past and traveled to current timeline using the same Eclipse gate.

So why didn't they disappear as well when the Eclipse gate was destroyed?

Possible plothole??

Comment: There is a change in the future line, rogue and lucy is from the future and the others are from the past. When they change the events who made the evil rogue and future lucy they simple dont exist anymore.

Comment: @Rezende But the dragons are also from the past just like the dragonslayers.

Comment: R.Eyes What Dragons? The ones who pass throw the gate come to the same time line of evil rogue

Comment: As I understand, the dragons come from 400 year ago in the past. The timeline where future Rouge comes from does not have dragons since Lucy closes the gate in that timeline that's why he traveled to timeline before Lucy closes the gate(which is the current timeline). check this answer: http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13898

Comment: i dont think so,  the dragons related to the dragon slayers come from 400 years ago but in the evil rogue time line he enter in the gate and travel to this time changing the time and travellying back throw the gate with the rest of the dragons. The dragons who create the dragon slayers have a diferent time line because this

Answer (score 4):

**First** (and more importantly): According to the Wikia page of the Eclipse Gate (sorry, I couldn't find the actual chapter where the princess actually explains this):

> Many years later, after a different Eclipse Gate is constructed, following the conclusion of the fourth day of the X791 Grand Magic Games, Arcadios and Yukino bring Lucy, Natsu and their friends before the gate while attempting to persuade Lucy to help with the Eclipse Project.

So this is not the same Eclipse Gate that was constructed by Zeref and used by Anna and Layla to bring the dragon slayers into the present, therefore destroying it can't have an effect on whether the dragon slayers are present in the current timeline or not.

**Second**: Evil Rogue and his dragons disappeared, because the gate that he used in the *future* to come back to the present was destroyed in the *present*, therefore he won't be able to use it to come back to the present, therefore he wouldn't be able to bring the dragons from the past. This same logic doesn't apply for time travel which brings people to the future: no matter what you do with the time travelling device *after* they arrived, they will be still there as there is no need for the time travelling device to keep them there.

(Other than this, yes, time travel in most of the stories sucks and is usually full of plot holes. Fairy Tail is no different, there are lots of open questions. With Eclipse destroyed why didn't we go back to the original timeline with 10000 dragons destroying everything? Or why did the city remained destroyed after the dragons disappeared? Well, at least we didn't get a "Back To The Future"-like "timelines slowly change, there's still time to save your parents' marriage" plot hole.)

Comment: Agreed. the Gate must exist at both points for the time travel to be possible.  Natsu and the others went from the past to the future, and the gate had already survived the middle part in order for them to do so. Rogue went fom the future to the past, and in his timeline, the gate existed at both points, but by traveling to the past, he created a new future, which once the gate was destroyed rendered his initial trip impossible, so time fixed the impossibility by sending them back to their own time.

Answer (score 0):

They also would have had to have built the gate 400 years in the past to bring the dragons so the whole idea is full of holes like a lot of Fairy Tail. Although it's a good show they just constantly contradict previously stated facts

Answer (score 0):

The gate was destroyed and got rid of future rogue and future lucy because they came from the future which didnt happen yet. And since it didnt happen they disappeared along with anything They changed like the dragons crossing the gate. It didnt make the dragon slayers disappear bevabecauseuse they crossed the gate a long ass time ago and it didnt have anything to do with future rogue or lucy. So anything before the grand magic games and before that would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible we didn't see the future with the 10000 dragons because Fro didn't die. Think of it, if Fro died, that means that Rough will kill Sting. That leads us to the war vs Zeref. Maybe Natsu didn't win since Sting was dead, so Rough probably did some stupid thing (that didn't lead to the manga place).

Because of that, maybe Zeref lost to Acnologia after he defeated Natsu and Acnologia controlled the world, or Natsu defeated Zeref but lost to Acnologia because Sting wasn't there, and Rough probably fought Acnologia and all the other dragon slayer.

Well maybe this thing is my theory but it sounds like something that would happen.